# Migrate cold database (freebsd) to mariaDb on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, disaster-recovery

I have a little bit of a pickle:
I have a freebsd based jail that ran nextcloud with mysqldb
The machine running the jail is broken. I still have the jail with the data.

Now I was wondering if I can get the previous database over to an ubuntu VM with the current version of mariadb (I don't know what version was running on the freebsd jail)

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Tried copying the DB files over but either mysql wouldnt start at all or no tables are available in the DB

Any help appreciated. I'd assume at least some other files are required to get that back up and running

best regards

Comment: Can you provide mysql log lines with error description?

Comment: it would be best to make a backup and then try to import the backup, this should run with out any problem. Recovering from frm files is described here numerous times

Comment: Hello
Sorry for the delay but I was out for the past two days.

I see the tables in the database but get the following error:
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 194 "Tablespace is missing for a table" from storage engine InnoDB

Comment: @nbk Yes that would be the best way. But I dont have that option anymore as I only have the actual files left but no running instance on freebsd i could run mysqldump or sth on.
I assume the shutdown of the files was a cleanshutdown that happended during the actual upgrade from TrueNAS Core to TrueNAS Scale.

So I am hoping for all files to be in proper condition

Comment: backups backup backups that is a very good motto in computer science, but try the approach here https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-tablespace-is-missing-for-table/

Comment: Hello
sadly I don't have the create statements for the tables.
I tried after clean nextcloud installation to discard the tables spaces and then copied the tables in again. Import does not work though as there is an error that import is not possible due to secondary indices. I would assume without the creation queries it might be hard to determine what indices are required to recreate them (after deletion before import)
I think it might be difficult to get the database imported then right?

Comment: @chas0r That may be caused by major MySQL version differences. Older versions supports both `antelope` and `barracuda` formats for InnoDB tables while newer releases have `antelope` deprecated completely. You have try to install something like MySQL 4.7 and, if you'll get your DB working - make a logical dump. Then install a latest stable release and load your databases from dump.

Comment: Hello
as I couldn't wait for the system to stay offline any longer I just restarted and imported the data back in again after manually configuring the webapp again

I check but couldn't find the logs on the old instance
the only thing I found was pkg upgrade notes in messages log which indicate that the old version was a 8.0 release while the new one is 10

Thanks for your help anyways guys/galls :)